# Forge CSV Data Adapter - Reference Application Data Visualization

Tags: data-visualization, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-designautomation

I hope you are all doing well. I've been recently trying to modify the AutoDesk reference application to allow me to create a heat-map with my own sensors data and my own model. However, I have been having difficulties. Has anyone done something similar before? Do you have to create two separate `.env` files or do you just change both the credentials for the FORGE_ID portion and the CSV portion in the same one?
Thank You, (I attached an example of what it looks like with only the CSV portion change.)

[Changed CSV portion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTeqC.jpg)

Comment: @petrbroz I saw your similar answer, but I was wondering about if I wanted my own model?

Answer (score 0):

The `.env` file must be unique as it is loaded by the **dotenv** package to add all these values as environment variable (NodeJS access these variables with `process.env.[VARIABLE_NAME]`).

To ensure your `.env` file is used by **dotenv**, you must set your `ENV` to local, if you look at `/server/router/index.js`, you will find these lines :

```
if (process.env.ENV == "local") {
    require("dotenv").config({
        path: __dirname + "/../.env",
    });
}
```

As you are on MacOS you could try this command : `export ENV=local && npm run dev` to start your server in dev mode.

The **CSV** portion you showed should work, just put all these lines into your current `.env` file and you should be able to use your own model AND add your own sensors data.

Comment: yeah man, I've been doing that command 'export ENV=local && npm run dev'. What I was wondering is if I needed two or one .env files because I know to upload your own file you modified the Forge Client portion and to upload the csv adapter data you modified the CSV section, and I want to do both of these things.

Comment: Only one `.env` file with all the variables inside ! Just ensure you have no variable duplicate.

Comment: this is my current `.env` file

Comment: `FORGE_CLIENT_ID=STEH552QxGShVxJYkxrIJUeKRj6 #changed 4 post
FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET=A54c9a8a #4 post
FORGE_ENV=AutodeskProduction
FORGE_API_URL=https://developer.api.autodesk.com
FORGE_BUCKET=tool.cosengineer.es #4 post
ENV=local
ADAPTER_TYPE=csv
CSV_MODEL_JSON=server/gateways/synthetic-data/device-models.json
CSV_DEVICE_JSON=server/gateways/synthetic-data/devices.json
CSV_FOLDER=server/gateways/csv/
CSV_DATA_START=2011-02-01T08:00:00.000Z  
CSV_DATA_END=2011-02-20T13:51:10.511Z 
CSV_DELIMITER="\t"
CSV_LINE_BREAK="\n"
CSV_TIMESTAMP_COLUMN="time"
CSV_FILE_EXTENSION=".csv"` @alexAR

Comment: `if (process.env.ENV == "local") {
    require("dotenv").config({
        path: __dirname + "/../.env",
    });
}`

Comment: And what problem do you have with this `.env` file ?

Comment: whenever I go to http://localhost:9000/upload and upload my file, and then it just goes to the empty black screen once it uploads

Comment: So this is a different problem than the one you asked on this question. Please open a new question for each different problem you encounter.

Comment: alright. i will